# Zend: Select object: How do I replace the selected columns set by from()?

Tags: php, zend-framework

first of all, that's what I'm trying to do:

In one of my classes in the library I want to count the total amount of rows of a search result. The class uses a select object set by the appendant model of the search result. My problem is now, this select() has already set the requested columns by from(), but to simply count the rows I just want to select the id, because the website has to to be performant. I can't simply change the values of the object, because I'm using it in the library and the variables are protected. Unfortunately, Zend has no function for the mySql count command and I don't want to use static mySql code, because it could be, that we switch our database system in the future.

Now here's my question:

Is there any possibility by Zend_Select how I could change the selected columns?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
       ->from('thetable', 'COUNT(*)');
```

replacing the 'thetable' with the correct table name.

Comment: I had to remove the constant FROM, too, but this is exacly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: I have some "inner joins" in my query and after resetting the COLUMNS, it automatically adds an "Inner join" with the FROM table! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is from a project and isn't tested, but one of these should work.

```
$select->from(array("table_name" => "table_name"), array("my_col" => "COUNT(id)"));
```

**OR**

```
$select->from(array("table_name"), array("my_col" => "COUNT(id)"));
```

This is the same as

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as my_col FROM table_name
```

Hope that helps

Jake

Comment: Unfortunately not, I get an exception: You cannot define a correlation name 'bd_users' more than once

Comment: You can pass an empty array as the first parameter, as you don't need to re-add the table. This way it won't try to re-declare the correlation.

Answer (score 1):

This one didn't work for me (I needed to select only from one joined table):

```
$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
   ->from('thetable', 'COUNT(*)');
```

Maybe because I had some joins. But nevertheless, here's the solution: to use reset() and then columns():

```
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from(['t1' => 'table1'])
        ->join(['t2' => 't2'], 't1.id = t2.t1_id')
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns('t1.*');
```

Just FYI, the version of Zend Framework is 1.12

Answer (score -1):

To use a mysql command in a select, you need to use Zend_Db_Expr:

```
$select = $this->select()
            ->from('myTable', new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(id) as count'));
echo $select; //SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM myTable;
```

Comment: I am not in a Model and I can not write this code inside of a model. Please read the question.

Comment: If you want to use count then proper way should be 
`from('myTable', array('count'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('count(*)'))`  (or ID instead of * if you need). but you never should alias anything yourself.